# Multiple Router outlets in different templates Angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-routing

I login using router-outlet tag in main app.component.html and if the login is successful i navigate to home page which is a different component consists of toolbar,side-nav and an area to display my dashboard content.Now in my home page i need another router-outlet where it displays the content upon choosing option in side-nav

my project structure is :

```
src

--login
----login.component.html
----login.component.ts
----login.component.css
--home-page
    dashboard
    --dashboard.component.html
    --dashboard.component.ts
----home.component.html
----home.component.ts
----home.component.css
--application-details
     app-overview
     --app-overview.component.html
     --app-overview.component.ts
----application.component.html
----application.component.ts
--users
----users.component.html
----users.component.ts
```

In my `app.component.html` has the following

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

In `login.componnet.ts`

upon success `this.route.navigate(['/home-page'])`

In my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
{ path:'', redirectTo:'/login',pathMatch:'full'},
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
{ path:'/home-page',component:HomePgaeComponent,
    children:[
         { path:'',component:DashboardComponent,outlet:'dashboard'},
         { path:'user',component:UsersComponent,outlet:'user'}, ]
   },
```

now as soon as i login based on success condition triggers the page 
navigates to dashboard which is inside home page like this

```
    <tool-bar></tool-bar>    
    <div>
    <side-menu></side-menu> 
    <div class="main-content">

       <router-outlet name="dashboard"></router-outlet>
       <router-outlet name="user"></router-outlet>

    </div>
  </div>
```

here when i click upon the user option from side-nav it appends dashboard 
content as well as "user" content.I have other options as well so for the 
very first time it loads the landing page perfectly but when i select other 
side-nav options all the other content is mixed up. So When i select options 
from side-nav that respective content should be loaded in content area of 
home page.another scenario is when i navigate to homepage i need to navigate 
to another page when i perform some click action in dashboard component.
I have gone through tutorials and there they were passing some ids through 
services and i have no idea how to do that. As per my knowledge i know that 
passing outlet name into router-outlet will fetch the content of that 
component likewise as many router i mention those many multiple routers will 
be generated.

Answer (score 0):

> here when i click upon the user option from side-nav it appends
>   dashboard content as well as "user" content

```
 <router-outlet name="dashboard"></router-outlet>
 <router-outlet name="user"></router-outlet>
```

Both are children of same component

```
{ path:'/home-page',component:HomePgaeComponent,
    children:[
         { path:'',component:DashboardComponent,outlet:'dashboard'},
         { path:'user',component:UsersComponent,outlet:'user'}, ]
},
```

Either you use same router outlet to render both dashboard and user or you have user router outlet inside dashboard and user is child of dashboard.

Comment: i dont want to render both content i want to render individual content such as when i click user option from sidenav i want to load user content in place of dashboard content. Also, as soon as i login it lands into dashboard content now if i select user option from sidenav only user content should be displayed.